# what is the easy way to compare cube data with that of data mart?

Tags: t-sql, ssas, business-intelligence, cube, datasourceview

I was trying to compare with the cube's data with that of data mart using TSQL query. It s hard for me to find where the columns used in the cube are coming from. Because the columns used in the cube are coming from data source view, but how do I know which table?

Help appreciated

Comment: It is not going to be an easy thing to do, as a single column in a data mart could be multiple different things in a cube.

Comment: i think the reverse is also true...right?  i.e. a single column in a cube could be a calculated column of different columns in data mart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with SQL Server Business Intelligence?  Very generically speaking, the "columns" that you're seeing are coming from the fact table(s), sliced across one or more dimensions (as defined by the dimension tables).

Your best bet is to inspect the cube via SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio, if you know how to use it.  [This link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173709.aspx) should get you started if you're a little shaky with using BIDS to design SSAS cubes.

Comment: Thanx...I had figured this one out already....The reason I was not getting any tables in the data mart that could possible contain the data I wanted was because the cube was using views and the names for the views was not distinct from table names...u know what i mean...the developer should have used 'vw' as prefix or suffix for us to understand....I appreciate your help any way...